# How to re-serve the image instead of redirect when no query string parameters are sent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

I am using the ImageReszier module with the AzureReader2 plugin.

Everything is working great, but I am trying to get one more requirement of mine working. I always need to re-serve the image from this website. I've found that ImageResizer will redirect to the Azure blog URL if there are no query string parameters found in the url string.

I would like to prevent this, and just re-serve the original image.

My main reason for this, is so I can support HTTPS with Azure blob storage for images that don't need to be resized.

Any config options to pull this off?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a config option for this in V4; for V3, you can 'hack' it by adding a placeholder query string value to any azure request during the `Config.Current.Pipeline.Rewrite` event. This [will bypass the Redirect behavior](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/master/Plugins/AzureReader2/AzureReader.cs#L106).

Or, just add a meaningless querystring to all of your image URLs that don't need resizing.